# How to create a project in VS2010 by using cocos2d-x 2.1.4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, box2d, cocos2d-x, luabind

I'm learning cocos2d-x and I want to create a project in VS, but I find that there is no template for VS, the version of cocos2d-x is 2.1.4. So I wonder what can I do to build a cocos2d-x project in VS2010 support both Lua and box2d

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install python 2.6
2. Open a command line window
3. Go to your **cocos2d-x-2.1.4\tools\project-creator** folder
4. Run **create_project.py**. Usage:

   create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp
5. Your project will be created in **cocos2d-x-2.1.4\projects**

Comment: If I want my cpp project support lua ,what can I do ? @Chen

Comment: @einverne use `-language lua`. Then you will get some cpp projects and initial lua codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the solution @Chen provided, I believe there is build-in box2d support. And you can add lua support following this step.

1.add "scripting/lua/proj.win32" project to your solution in visual studio.
2.right click solution, and add "liblua" rely to your project.

rebuild your project. And add

```
#include <CCLuaEngine.h>
```